# Mysql pdo column type, name, and value

Tags: mysql, pdo, metadata, database-schema

I am using php 7.2, mysql pdo and trying to get the Column type, name, and value.  I have been using this that has done me well for the column name and value but now i would like to dynamically read the type (varchar,text,date  ect...)

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id = :id limit 1";

$st = $db->prepare($sql);
$st->execute([":id" => $id]);
$row = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if (count($row) >= 1) {
    foreach ($row as $column => $value) {
            $$column = $value; 
        }

}
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php

Answer (score 0):

Try executing the following query:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM myTable;
```

For example:

```
mysql> SHOW COLUMNS FROM price;
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| price_id       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| effective_date | date         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| min_quantity   | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| price          | decimal(7,0) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Column **Field will give you the column name**, **Type the column type**, Null will be 'NO' or 'YES' depending on whether the column is nullable, Key will be 'PRI' if the column is part of the primary key, etc. Read the manual.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but i am not sure this is everything i am looking for.  I am trying to be able to echo the Column Type, Column Name, and its value for the specified row.  My example does that but does not retrieve the column type...